# select specific Git branch in Jenkins Declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, git-branch, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to select branches with branch names starting with release.

```
stage("Upload Artifacts") {
      when {
          expression {
              return env.BRANCH_NAME == "release/*"
          }
      }
      steps {
          ...
          ...
      }
 }
```

The above code is not picking up my release branch and is simply skipping the stage.

**Stage "Upload Artifacts" skipped due to when conditional**

Comment: Does your branch have `*` in its name?

Comment: No, my branch name is release/newrelease. I want to select all branches starting with release.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the branch name with the verbatim string `release/*`. If there is only one branch called `"release"` just compare with that. If you wanted to use the `*` as a wild card you should use `BRANCH_NAME.startsWith('release')` or look into patterns in groovy.

Comment: Great, could you mark the answer as accepted then? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
when {
     expression {
         return (env.BRANCH_NAME).startsWith('release')
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.